# Use Varibles in random? (python)

Tags: python

so im a python beginner and i cant find a way to put a input varible in a random like so,

```html
import time
import random
choice = input('easy (max of 100 number), medium(max of 1000) or hard (max of 5000)? Or custom)')
time.sleep(2)
if choice == 'custom':
    cus = input(' max number?')
print ('okey dokey!')
eh = 1
cuss = random.randrange(0, (cus))
easy = random.randint(0, 100)
medium = random.randint(0, 1000)
hard = random.randint (0, 5000)
if choice == 'easy' or 'medium' or 'hard' or cus:
    while eh == 1:
        esy = int(input('what do you think the number is?)'))
        if esy > easy:
            time.sleep(2)
            print ('too high!')
        elif esy == easy:
            print (' CORRECT!')
            break
        elif esy < easy:
            print ('TOO low')
```

is there any way i can put a number that someone typed in a random, like in line 9?

Comment: remove your brackets and just use `(0, int(cus))`

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things wrong with your code.  You're using ('s with print, which suggests you're using python3.  This means that when you do `cus = input()`, cus is now a string.  You probably want to do `cus = int(input())`

Doing `choice == 'easy' or 'medium' or 'hard' or cus` will always be True; I have no idea why people keep doing this in Python, but you need to do `choice == 'easy' or choice == 'medium' or choice == 'hard' or choice == 'cus'`.  Of course, a better way to do it is with a dictionary.

```
values = {'easy': 100, 'medium': 1000, 'hard': 5000}
```

And then do

```
value = values.get(choice)
if not value:
   value = int(input("Please enter custom value"))
```

And then you can do 
`randomvalue = random.randint(1,value)`

Comment: i see where i went qrong tahnks!

Answer (score 0):

Convert your variable `cus` to an int and pass it as you normally would

```
cuss = random.randrange(0, int(cus))
```